# Seemingly paradoxical logarithm manipulations inside strange gaussian like double integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, logarithms, branch-cuts

I've been playing around with an integral that seems to give two contradictory results and I cannot figure out why. Let $a$ be some real positive constant.

Then on the one hand, we can consider the integral

$I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dy\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx\frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{y^2}{2}} \left(\log (a x)-\log (a y)\right)}{(x-i y)^2}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dy\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx\frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{y^2}{2}} \left(\log (x)-\log (y)\right)}{(x-i y)^2}$,

where admittedly one may have factors of $\pm i \pi$ whether $x$ and $y$ are positive or negative, but nonetheless we see $\log(a)$ drops out of the formula.

But on the other hand, we consider the log integrals separately:

$I_1=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dy\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx\frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{y^2}{2}} \log (a x)}{(x-i y)^2}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dy\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx\frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{y^2}{2}} \log (a x)}{(x^2+ y^2)^2}(x^2+2i x y-y^2)$,

$I_2=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dy\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx\left(-\frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{y^2}{2}} \log (a y)}{(x-i y)^2}\right)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dy\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx\frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{y^2}{2}} \log (a y)}{(x^2+ y^2)^2}(y^2-2i x y-x^2)$.

Now changing variables in $I_2$ such that $x$ is renamed $y$ and vice versa, we finally obtain

$I=I_1+I_2=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dy\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx  \left(2\frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{y^2}{2}} \log (a x)}{(x^2+ y^2)^2}(x^2-y^2)\right)$

How could it be that in one way the $\log(a)$ term vanished but another way it does not?

One can actually compute this base double integral on mathematica for example. We find

$I_1=-\frac{\pi}{2}(1+\gamma-\log[-\frac{a^2}{2}] )$.

So I am trying to figure out what is the actual value of I in my case.

Comment: The limits of integration are not clear for me. Further, how do you define log(x) as x->0? Indeed, |log(x)| goes to infinity as x tends to zero. Moreover, the divisor in your integrand, x+iy, does not help to eliminate that problem. It seems that the integrand is not "nice" enough to give a result calculable by, for example, Fubini's theorem.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. it should be -infinity to infinity always. Regarding log[x], we can just take $-\pi<arg[x]\leq\pi$. The question is more regarding the apparent manipulation which removes $\log(a)$ entirely from the question, and the other manipulation which very much keeps it and is there in the final answer. The two cannot both be true so I must be doing something wrong

Comment: Why did you exchange x and y in the second equation? That seems improper.

Comment: Do you mean right before I write $I=I_1+I_2$? it's because x and y are dummy variables i can just rename them as I please

Comment: @sillyQsman indeed, your integral goes over zero, so, how are you dealing with |log(x)| exploding at zero? (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm) None of the other terms prevents that exploding. Therefore, since you are NOT dealing objects that are well defined over the entire area of integration, I don't see how your manipulations make sense. You have something which is akin to the proof that 1 = 2 (https://www.math.toronto.edu/mathnet/falseProofs/first1eq2.html)

Comment: Just because it goes through zero isn't good enough reason to ignore it. It can still make sense, see principal value integrals https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value . For example, $\int_{-2}^{2}dx \log(x)=4\log(2)-4+2\pi i$ is perfectly well defined even though the integrand 'explodes near 0'. And if you didn't follow a part of my manipulation, you should be specific about which part instead of claiming it makes no sense without saying which part (perhaps you just didn't follow a part of the manipulation?).

Comment: If you mean a principal value integral, then you should use notation which denotes a principal value integral.  One standard notation is $$\operatorname{PV}\!\!\int_{a}^{b} f(z)\,\mathrm{d}z.$$  Otherwise, the default assumption is that this notation denotes a bog-standard Riemann integral.

Comment: nonetheless my point still stands that the question should not be ignored just because the integrand appears ill defined at particular points. I was merely making the point that the question can still be valid (for example, I'm not even sure if the PV is needed for both integrals, perhaps just one). Instead of being hung up on the notation used to ask the question, why not just take a quick look at the two manipulations and see that what I'm confused about is how one can lead to 'log(a) independence' whereas the other very much does not. That was the main point of the question.

Comment: I do not think that people are `hung up' on the notation: the concern is if the object you wrote down exists at all, and if it does not then how are *you* choosing to assign a value to it

Comment: I understand that- if I was able to make perfect sense of the setup (ie whether the integral need PV prescription, whether it's needed for just one of the integrals or the double integral), I would state the question with more precise notation. But that is perhaps the source of the problem/ confusion in the first place- which is why I just asked that one looks at the two 'manipulations' to see what appears to the contradiction. perhaps by doing that, one would be able to point out how / why one of the manipulations is ill defined (e.g. since a PV prescription is needed somewhere specific)

Comment: I just feel that the comments thus far have all been so concerned with whether the question was stated notationally precise enough to be warranted any consideration at all: I was protesting that that isn't helpful, since it may be that a careful stating of the problem already involves an understanding which would resolve the problem in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

The issue might be that the integral containing $\log(x)$ in each case has to be treated with the principal value prescription. As such, the very first line may not make sense and should instead be written as

$I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dy \left(\text{PV} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx e^{\frac12 x^2-\frac12 y^2}\frac{\log(a x)}{(x-i y)^2}\right)-\left(\text{PV} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dy \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx e^{\frac12 x^2-\frac12 y^2}\frac{\log(a y)}{(x-i y)^2}\right)$.

In that case the initial cancellation of $\log(a)$ would not occur, and the second manipulation would still be valid.

This seems to make sense, but of course the best approach would be to just perform numerical integration of I and see what the result agrees with.